# Using Visual Studio SSIS lookup function to find matching dates

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl

I am looping through a folder with hundreds of .csv files that are formatted in a standardized way with 5 years of daily financial data in each. I am attempting to put a single column (the day's opening value) from each into their respective column names in a larger SQL server table. The process is meant to handle like the following:

```
File_1 
------------  
day   open
---   -----
1      100
2      200
3      300

File_2
------------- 
day    open 
-----  ----- 
 1       50 
 2       100 
 3       150

Integration Opens Table
-------------------------
day   file_1   file_2
----  -------  -------
1      100       50
2      200       100
3      300       150
```

I have a process built in Visual Studio using SSIS that loops through the files in one folder is supposed to lookup the matching dates and input the open data for that matching date in its respective column.

The project runs without error but no data is transferred and I suspect it is surrounding the lookup function as I am trying to use it as a `WHERE` clause to just match the dates. I also ignore failures for no matching entries as I am only interested in the matches (similar to an inner join).

My questions are does the Lookup function in Visual Studio work the way I am assuming? If not, is there a way to make it function like this (such as an SQL query) or is there a more appropriate operator? Here is how the process is currently configured.
[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When choosing the `Ignore Failure` option, it means that when the lookup did not matches the lookup column `DateRec` will be `NULL` (row will not be ignored only the output value), so you have to add a conditional split after the lookup the filter rows where `DataRec` is null using the following expression

```
ISNULL([DateRec]) == True
```

Comment: This did work and I thank you for your help, can you explain what you're doing in that conditional in more depth? From my understand it looks at where the DateRec is null and places it in the destination based on that. Why does that work in this situation when the records themselves are null but not the date?